# VBA Move files via LAN network doesn't work

Tags: vba, move, filesystemobject

Im struggling with moving files via Local Network using VB script.
The problem is that at my local directory it works, but when I try use it on another computer on LAN it doesn't. Using very simple code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
folderPath = "C:\Test\test.txt"
outFilePath = "C:\Test2\test.txt"
fso.MoveFile folderPath, outFilePath
```

And on my local computer it works. Then changing paths for another computer in LAN connection:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
folderPath = "\\computerName\Test\test.txt"
outFilePath = "\\computerName\Test2\test.txt"
fso.MoveFile folderPath, outFilePath
```

And it doesn't. I've shared this folders on network, switched off Windows defender, tested lots of path combination(IP address instead of name, added C location before computer name and so on). LAN works. Destination computer has Windows Enterprise LTSC.

Comment: Did you check the share on your destination folder to make sure you have write access? What is the actual error you get?

Comment: I get 'Runtime error... Method MoveFile of object 'IFILESYSTEM3' failed' .

Comment: Did you check the share on your destination folder to make sure you have write access?